# How do you reverse this string using a for loop

Tags: python, string, reverse

how do I modify the code so that it reverses the string?

```
str = "pizza"
def letterReverse(word):
    newStr = ""
    for letter in word:
        newStr += letter
    return newStr
print(letterReverse(str))
```

Comment: `str` is not a good variable name: you shadow the built-in [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str). you could use: `"".join(reversed("pizza"))`.

Comment: Prepend `letter` to `newStr` rather than appending it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your line `newStr += letter`. That adds the new letter to the right end of `newStr`, but you want to add it to the left side. So change that line to `newStr = letter + newStr`. You also should avoid using `str` as a variable name, so I changed it to `oldstr`. Your new code is then

```
oldstr = "pizza"
def letterReverse(word):
    newStr = ""
    for letter in word:
        newStr = letter + newStr
    return newStr
print(letterReverse(oldstr))
```

The output from that is what you want:

```
azzip
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
str = "pizza"
new_str = str[::-1]
```

If you want to modify your code just add [::-1] in your loop:

```
str = "pizza"
def letterReverse(word):
    newStr = ""
    for letter in word[::-1]:
        newStr += letter
    return newStr
print(letterReverse(str))
```

Comment: @ncica I know thats why I added two first lines, to show how it can be achieved faster. 
I added this code only cause OP wanted to modify his code.